# Dynamics between sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of LIST MEMBERS, link image:

[image]

The Events Sheet link image (the calendar)

[image]

The value of the dropdown is where each member selects is name from the "List Members". Is it possible in my sheet List Members in same row to put all the events that have the name of the Member? Like "Event + Date" How can i achieve this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: or at least how can get what list of cells where the member of their name?

Comment: Please use the EDIT button to add information to your question. Additional information should NOT be added as comments.

Comment: Also, if you can provide at least a mockup of what you want the List Members sheet to look like. It's difficult to tell precisely what you are asking, and an image of the desired outcome may be helpful.